# How to functionally achieve this waveform in LTspice without using PWL source

Tags: ltspice

First of all, I start by the following pulse waveform:

[image]

using the LTspice interface as follows:

[image]

But what I need is that: I want the pulse to be ON(3.3V) between time = 1s and 2s or infinity. How can that be achieved using SPICE command in LTspice?

Comment: It's unclear from reading your question to know exactly what you want. Draw the waveform you want and we can tell you how to achieve it. The way to do complex waveform is with a PWL. It is much easier.

Comment: I mean I want to keep those 2 cycle pulses as it is like in the blue plot. But additionally I want the same waveform to be ON between second 1 and second 2.

Comment: Ok maybe the PWL is only way to go

Comment: Its not, but PWL is the most clear way.

Comment: Have you heard of OR gates?

Comment: @user1245 Why is the PWL not wanted? The way I see it you need at least *two* sources to achieve this, while the PWL does it in one go: `pwl repeat for 2 0 0 1m 3.3 0.2 3.3 +1m 0 0.4 0 +1m 3.3 0.6 3.3 +1m 0 1 0 endrepeat`. BTW, there's no need to exaggerate with 1 ns rise/fall times in a 0.2 s width pulse -- 1 ms is just fine. But, if you really want them sharp, then you can go as low as 1 us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two pulse sources and then add them together with a b-source.

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh....so that's what they wanted.  The text in the question made zero sense to me.

Comment: just connect the two pulse sources in series.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the waveform to be *on* past 1s, you can try this.

[image]

The the rise & fall times are subtracted from Ton, {0.2-1u}, to create a 50% duty cycle and to align the two waveforms so you won't get glitches during the transitions.